# I need to make my scatter plot legend dots bigger but w/o overlap them

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, scatter-plot, legend-properties

I'm having issues with a scatter plot legend: I need the size of the legend dots to be bigger, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to multiply 'sizes' * 100 but then in the legend the dots overlap. Thanks for your help.

here's my code:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
y = np.array([13,27,36,9,10,22,62,77,42,46])
sizes = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,3,9,5,2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, s=sizes)

handles, labels = scatter.legend_elements(prop="sizes", 
alpha=0.6)
ax.legend(
    handles,
    labels,
    loc="lower right",
    bbox_to_anchor=(1.27, 0.5),
    ncol=2, frameon=False
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The legend has a keyword `markerscale=` to scale the markers up or down compared to how they look in the plot. Note that this scale is linear (`0.5` means half as wide, while the `s=` parameter of `plt.scatter()` is relative to the *area* of the marker).

Here is an example, scaling the markers on the plot by `100` and halving the dots in the legend:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
y = np.array([13, 27, 36, 9, 10, 22, 62, 77, 42, 46])
sizes = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 9, 5, 2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, s=sizes * 100)

handles, labels = scatter.legend_elements(prop="sizes", alpha=0.6)
ax.legend(handles, labels,
          loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.5),
          markerscale=0.5,
          ncol=2, frameon=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.plot()
```

[image: scatter plot with scaled markers in the legend]

Comment: If this answers your question, you might consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark, turning it from grey into green